# Is there a pure Python Lucene?

Tags: python, full-text-search, lucene, ferret

The ruby folks have [Ferret](https://github.com/dbalmain/ferret). Someone know of any similar initiative for Python? We're using PyLucene at current, but I'd like to investigate moving to pure Python searching.

Comment: Probably not an answer to the question, but Elasticsearch implements a simple web interface on top of Lucene, and PyES is a python wrapper over Elasticsearch. I have used pyES comfortably, but some advanced features present in Lucene are still missing from Elasticsearch.

Comment: By the way, the old Ferret URL redirects now to http://www.chandanweb.com/solutions/web-applications.html - I've replaced the URL with the new github page https://github.com/dbalmain/ferret :)

Comment: For accessing Lucene indices I found (and am trying out) `plush`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plush/0.3.0

Comment: any reason for going for pure python?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Whoosh](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/) is a new project which is similar to lucene, but is pure python.

Comment: Just used whoosh for a project and it really was easy to use.  No messing around at all - just worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, whoosh seems to be abandoned now (and has a lot of bad bugs).

Comment: it won't work with >1G data. merging segments takes hour

Comment: also updating/deleting documents does not really work. search still returns those deleted/overwritten documents.

Answer (score 6):

The only one pure-python (not involving even C extension) search solution I know of is [Nucular](http://nucular.sourceforge.net/). It's slow (much slower than PyLucene) and unstable yet.

We moved from PyLucene-based home baked search and indexing to [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) but YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

I recently found [pyndexter](http://swapoff.org/pyndexter). It provides abstract interface to various different backend full-text search engines/indexers. And it ships with a default pure-python implementation.

These things can be disastrously slow though in Python.

Comment: I came here looking for something to access Lucene indices in python, I'm not too concerned about speed at this point. I just don't want to be tied to Java. So thanks for the pynter.

Comment: Last release of pyndexter was 2007 and the link provided here is dead, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

For some applications pure Python is overrated. Take a look at Xapian.

Comment: Thanks for the Xapian mention. Not what I need right now, but I'll sure keep it in mind for later.

Answer (score 2):

[lupy](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=76541&package_id=77267) was a lucene port to pure python.[The lupy people suggest that you use PyLucene](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/WhitherLupy). Sorry. Maybe you can use the Java sources in combination with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/Project/).

Comment: It's interesting that Ferret seems to be very appreciated and used while Lupy was abandoned.

Comment: Well, PyLucene seems to cater to a similar community. Also, some people are even ready to do their full-text searches in Java because of Lucene ;-)

Answer (score 2):

+1 to the Xapian and Pyndexter answers.

Ferret is actually written in C with Ruby bindings on top.  A pure Ruby search engine would be even slower than a pure Python one.  I would love to see "someone else" write a Cython/Pyrex layer for Python interface to Ferret, but won't do it myself because why bother when there are Python bindings for Xapian.

Comment: Thanks. I used the term "pure" in a dirty way. =) If I can install it with easy_setup of the like I'm happy.

Answer (score 2):

For non-pure Python, [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com) with Python API works the fastest. From the benchmarks from multiple blogs, Sphinx Search is way faster than Lucene, uses way less memory and it is in C.

I am developing a multi-document search engine based on it, using python and [web2py](http://web2py.com) as framework.

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of searching for this, I found a nice Python solution: [repoze.catalog](http://static.repoze.org/catalogdocs/). It's not strictly Python-only because it uses ZODB for storage, but it seems a better dependency to me than something like SOLR.

Comment: I want Solr in python, what was a conclusion about software like Solr but written in Python?