# lucene / python

Tags: python, lucene

Can I use lucene directly from python, preferably without using  a binary module?

I am interested mainly in read access -- being able to perform queries from python over existing lucene indexes.

Answer (score 8):

You can't use Lucene itself from CPython without using a binary module, no.

You could use it directly from [Jython](http://jython.org/), or you could use a Python port of Lucene, eg. [Lupy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Lupy/0.2.1) (though Lupy is no longer under development).

If you're prepared to relax your non-binary requirement, [PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/) is a wrapper that embeds Java Lucene into Python.

This similar question offers some options: [Is there a pure Python Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438315/is-there-a-pure-python-lucene)

Answer (score 8):

[PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/) is a Python wrapper around Lucene. Therefore, you have to install Lucene as well, and its installation may be a bit complex (especially on Windows!)